# Laravel 5.6 Redis as dependency injection

Tags: laravel

have been searching through the documentation but to no avail... How should I inject Redis cache through Dependency injection instead of using the Redis facade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all underlying classes in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades#facade-class-reference. For Redis, it's `\Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager`. But for caching, I recommend using the [default cache driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache#cache-usage)  `\Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory` because Laravel will namespace the keys behind the scene. If redis isn't the default cache driver, you may specify the store like this:

`$cache->store('redis')->get('foo');`

Comment: Thank you. I somehow managed to skip the Facade class reference part.